# How to use an IF statement to compare value against array in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[image: Image of Google Sheet Data]

In cell A4, I have a value, lets say **clt**. In A5 I have the following formula:

```
=if(A4 = {A$1:$C$3}, 0, "Yes!")
```

Clearly, it's not working but I hope you can appreciate the logic I am attempting. Also, this is a quick representation of my example as the actual dataset is confidential.

Any direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A4=A1:C3, 0, "Yes!"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a way to display only "Yes!" in that example versus it showing over multiple cells ?

Comment: not sure I understand... can you explain a bit more? or provide some visual example?

Comment: See screenshot here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Rq7K-woFJKXF9GW-nwrFBh9cTwtwREn/view?usp=sharing Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Sorry, instead of "Y" with our example, should be "Yes!"

Comment: The sheet can be accessed here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hIk3LhE4utUIkHI1p56H01XbZUDDi3iwHfaG4NVWRrc/edit#gid=1918103351

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this via a COUNTIF function

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:C3,A3)>0,"Yes!")
```